# Pass client id to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there some way to pass the unique client id to codebehind? I have a imagebutton in a gridview and I wish to do something like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imbView" runat="server" ToolTip="View details" ImageUrl="~/css/images/View.png" CommandName="wView" CommandArgument='#<%=imbView.ClientID%>' />
```

On debugging though I see that my `CommandArgument` is `#<%=imbView.ClientID%>`..

To specify: I want to pass something that uniquely identifies generated elements (and I thought that the ClientID would be a good way to identify it).

Comment: `#<%=imbView.ClientID%>` is not a valid syntax. It should be `<%# imbView.ClientID%>`; even then it doesn't make sense to pass client id like that to server side. **Where do you want to access that Server Control?** In other words, what is the name of the event?

Comment: @Win Not sure I understand what you mean, but this is in a gridview and the imagebutton uses my specified `OnRowCommand`. In my `OnRowCommand` I can access the `CommandName` and the `CommandArgument`. But this doesn't really help me if I cant send a CommandArgument that uniquely identifies my button (or cell, or row)

Comment: Please post the code that you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh ?

Assuming you have

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imbView" runat="server" ToolTip="View details" ImageUrl="~/css/images/View.png" CommandName="wView" OnCommand="aaa" />
```

then -

```
 protected void aaa(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       var a= (sender as Control).ClientID;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, But since this is a Gridview, that just gives me the ClientID of the gridview, not the actual image button

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you retrieve CommandArgument inside [RowCommand event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can also use `e.CommandSource as ImageButton` inside RowCommand event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detail">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imbView" runat="server"
                    ToolTip="View details" ImageUrl="~/css/images/View.png"
                    CommandName="wView"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Name = "John"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Eric"},
        };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "wView")
    {
        var imageButton = e.CommandSource as ImageButton;
        string clientId = imageButton.ClientID;

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```